# How to make Static navbar fadeIn on scroll - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the navbar fadeIn and become fixed when user scrolls down. I could only make it sticky, and that's not what I am looking for. How could I make it fade in from the top of the page on scroll?

This is what I made so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 110) {
            $('.navbar-light').addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            $('.navbar-light').removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moerayan/DTcHh/25773/

Basically, what I am trying to do, on scroll, the navbar should fade in and not stick!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve. If the navbar is always visible, how can it fade in?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried to hide it and then fade in, but didn't workout. You can ignore my script, if you can only enlighten me with the logic I should use to achieve this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Basically, what I am trying to do, on scroll, the navbar should fade in and not stick

Comment: But if it doesn't stick on scroll then it won't be visible on the page when the fade happens. It's still not clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your fiddle is just make the nav-bar sticky.

Because I can not guess how your `html` is looking like. And if you are using some plugin I just can say this:

You can not do this with just little `jquery`

The site you are pointing to is using this plugin to achieve the effect.

https://github.com/markgoodyear/headhesive.js/

And of course the related `html` in order to make it work.

This plug in has also its demo site where you can se the examples and make this to work as you want.

https://markgoodyear.com/labs/headhesive/

I hope this will help you out. :)

Comment: Yes Franco, That solved my problem. Thank you indeed!